# Cant access object properties java

Tags: java, object, properties

```
List<Employeee> employees = new ArrayList<>();
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String[] input = new String[6];
int n = Integer.valueOf(scanner.nextLine());
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    input = scanner.nextLine().split(" ");
    employees.add(new Employeee(input[0], Double.parseDouble(input[1]), input[2], input[3], input[4],
            Integer.valueOf(input[5])));
}
for (Object i : employees) {
        System.out.println(i.sallary); //And here ofc idk what to do to print them
        System.out.println(i.name);
}
```

So here i just make a couple of object from my custom class and i put them inside of the list.
And after that i iterate over that list with a for loop and there i want to print their properties, but it doesn't let me. My Employeee class is simple I wont even paste the getters and setters from it.

```
public class Employeee {

    private String name;
    private double sallary;
    private String possition;
    private String department;
    private String email;
    private int age;

    public Employeee(String name, double sallary, String possition, String department, String email, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.sallary = sallary;
        this.possition = possition;
        this.department = department;
        this.email = email;
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

Comment: What does "it doesn't let me" mean?

Comment: Also, is `sallay` intended to be spelled without the `r` here or is that a typo?

Comment: when i say in the for loop `i.sallay` i want to print the current objects sallary. I aslo made mistake cause itallij didint gave intallisence and i mispelled it.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, _a specific problem or error_ and _the shortest code necessary_ to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: 'Doesn't let me' is not a problem description. You've made the member fields private. *Ergo*, they are private. They can't be accessed from outside the class. Why is this a surprise? You're also using a wild variety of spellings. Try the correct ones in all cases. `salary` and `position`, for example. The compiler won't accept mis-spelling, and neither will most employers, or customers, or users, or colleagues.

Comment: @Joe C I create objects from a console input and then put then in a list, then i itterate over that list with a for loop and ofr each object in the for loop i want to print their sallary and names

Comment: I know that.  I can read code.  The reason I have voted to close it is because you have failed to provide any kind of explanation for "it doesn't let me", such as an error message.

Comment: You mentioned that your `Employeee` class has getters and setters.  Why aren't you using them to get the properties you want?

Comment: Idk how can i make the discription any better than that, idk what i haven't discribed rly. `java: cannot find symbol`  `symbol:variable name` `location: variable i of type java.lang.Object` thats the error massage. It doesn't helps. Don't tell me it makes a difference in the post. And pleace if you answer give me an exaple discription pls.

Comment: **OF COURSE IT HELPS. OF COURSE IT MAKES A DIFFERENCE TO THE POST.** Don't be ridiculous.

Comment: And where in the `Object` class will you find anything called `name`?  (Note: I said the `Object` class, not the `Employeee` [sic] class, because the compiler will be looking in `Object`.)

Comment: And please cut out the random spelling and txt msg abbreviations. This is not an SMS message system.

Comment: Change `for (Object i : employees) {` to `for (Employeee i : employees) {`.

Comment: Louis Wasserman. Thank you men, This is what i wanted. It worked as i wated it to. If you want post it i will give it best answer if the topic doesn't get deleted

Comment: It didn't work as you wanted to unless you also did something about using the accessor functions or making the fields non-private.

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous problems here.

1. You are mis-spelling your attribute names with wild abandon.
2. You are using `Object` in the for-each statement where you should be using `Employee`.
3. The fields you are trying to access directly from outside the class are declared as `private`, which means you can't. You should be using the respective accessor functions instead.